# sudo apt-get update couldn't create temporary file

Tags: windows, ubuntu, updates, sudo, apt-get

Tried to do `sudo apt-get update`, get this response every time I run it:

```
Get:1 http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian xenial InRelease [1814 B]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:1 http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian xenial InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.RpjjUo for passing config to apt-key
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.IvhgJr for passing config to apt-key
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.F98B6M for passing config to apt-key
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.WWtE1d for passing config to apt-key
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.TP8dgO for passing config to apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian xenial InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.RpjjUo for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.IvhgJr for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.F98B6M for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.WWtE1d for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.TP8dgO for passing config to apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Tried `sudo apt-get clean`, nothing happened. `sudo apt-get upgrade` states that there is nothing that needs to be upgraded. `sudo apt-get check` doesn't find anything either.

Using Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Comment: To me this looks like a problem with tmp. Can you `touch /tmp/test`?

Comment: @LAROmega I got `touch: cannot touch '/tmp/test': Permission denied`

Comment: Make sure /tmp exists. Not sure why it wouldn't but the Ubuntu Linux Subsystem should have it has part of root's file system.

Comment: @LAROmega [It exists](https://i.imgur.com/ScshScr.png)

Comment: i had faced same issue in docker , a quick solution would be to do `sudo chmod 777 /tmp` and it worked for me

Comment: Better quick solution: `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`. see my answer below

Answer (score 76):

You probably changed the file permissions on your `/tmp` folder, check with

```
ls -lad /tmp
```

The normal settings for `/tmp` are 1777, which `ls` shows as `drwxrwxrwt`. That is: wide open, except that only the owner of a file can remove it (that's what this extra `t` bit means for a directory).

If the settings are wrong, you can restore them with:

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

I would recommend rebooting the machine after making this change.

If you cannot reboot, check the answers here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71625/20661

Another possibility would be that something is mounted to /tmp. Check with

```
mount | grep /tmp
```

NOTE: also check `/var/tmp` the same way, maybe you have the same error there

Answer (score 7):

For me, I was using a Docker container and had mounted a directory to `/tmp` in the container, which was causing the conflict. I removed the mounted directory to `/tmp` and that allowed `apt update` to work.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem with docker. I had to remove a number of docker images and rebuild them. This happened after I changed docker's root dir.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in VS Code dev container because I had a trailing `\` in my Dockerfile. This can cause other issues like in here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7319

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was my disk had errors.

`ls -lad /tmp` was fine, showing `drwxrwxrwt`, [as explained in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1541135/425838).

**So, it turns out I had to run `fsck` on the root dir.**

Run `df -h` first to see what disks you have. Find the one mounted as your *root* disk at mount point `/`. Mine is `/dev/mapper/sda4_crypt`. So, I had to run this:

```bash
fsck /dev/mapper/sda4_crypt -y
```

...[as explained by this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/817660/327339).

I figured it out because I rebooted to see if that would help my `sudo apt update` error problem, and my system was unable to boot. It booted into the `initramfs` menu instead, as explained by the Q&A I linked to just above.

Then, after [following those instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/817660/327339) and rebooting from the `initramfs` menu like this:

```bash
fsck /dev/mapper/sda4_crypt -y
reboot
exit
```

...then once logged back in, `sudo apt update` worked again!

Previously, it was showing various `Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.RpjjUo for passing config to apt-key` type errors as shown in this question.

Once `sudo apt update` worked again, I had to do this, as [quoted from my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1444179/327339):

> ```bash
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt full-upgrade
> # ...which told me to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, so I did that:
> sudo apt --fix-broken install
> ```
>
> Then, re-run the Software Updater GUI tool.

### See also

1. My comment here, where I refer back to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox/817660#comment2520181_817660

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when *building* Docker images starting from Ubuntu images  on an IBM Power9 machine.

When I started from the image `ubuntu:focal` with image ID `0a648e725100` I didn't have this problem. `ls -ld /tmp` (when run in the image) indeed shows permissions `drwxrwxrwt`, and the Dockerfile build instruction `RUN apt-get update` works (as does the rest, not shown).

However, there is another image called `ppc64le/ubuntu:22.04`, image ID `5c1fccf2a735` in which the permissions of `/tmp`, for whatever reason, were set to `drwxr-xr-t` and `RUN apt-get update` failed with the error message shown in the OP.

Adding `RUN chmod 1777 /tmp` to the Dockerfile solved the problem.

**UPDATE** : I encountered the same problem with the `jupyter/datascience-notebook:hub-3.1.1` image, architecture `X86_64`, ID=`f4ae5f5cf82a` as well. This image is derived from an Ubuntu image. There must have been a `/tmp` permission problem in Ubuntu 22.04 itself which is not architecture- or image-dependent.